# How to schedule a task that runs everyday in 13.00 h

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm using `Quartz` library to run a schedule task.I used it like this

```
ISchedulerFactory scheduleFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            IScheduler scheduler = scheduleFact.GetScheduler();
            scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>()
                            .WithIdentity("myjob", "group 1")
                            .Build();


            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                            .WithIdentity("mytrigger", "group 1")
                            .StartNow()
                            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                                .WithIntervalInSeconds(60*60*12)
                                .RepeatForever())
                            .Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

this works fine.that means the schedule runs for every 12 hours.but what I want is to run the task everyday when the time is 13.00.how can I do that.hope your help.

Comment: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html

Comment: You'd use `StartAt(date)` where `date` specifies the future (nearest) 13:00. Then, repeat every 24 hours, repeat forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
  .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(s => s
      .OnEveryDay()
      .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(13, 00)))
      .EndingDailyAfterCount(1))
.Build();
```

Tipp: Output the next 10 runs on console for debugging purpose.

```
var times = TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimes(trigger as IOperableTrigger, null, 10);
foreach (var time in times) Console.WriteLine(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a job with `WithSchedule` and use `CronScheduleBuilder` to define the job frequency -

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("mytrigger", "group1")
    .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(13, 00))
    .ForJob(myJobKey)
    .Build();
```

Or, alternatively you can also use Cron expression while creating your job with `WithCronSchedule`

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("mytrigger", "group1")
    .WithCronSchedule("0 00 13 * * ?")
    .ForJob("myJob", "group1")
    .Build();
```

More details can be found [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html).